# 'slc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, node.js, strongloop

I am trying to get StrongLoop working on my Windows 7 machine.

I installed it with npm install -g strongloop

It threw some python errors, which seems to be expected and then execution finished.

I did the npm install npm step as indicated here: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Installing+StrongLoop#InstallingStrongLoop-Windows

When I try 'slc' on the command line it gives the above error.  I added it to the path manually and still nothing. Even when I go right into the directory where the slc file is ({user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\bin) and try to use it from there it says the same thing. Like the file that was installed is not executable.

Is this the right file? Is there another one somewhere? Drawing a blank here.

Comment: You should make sure your python version is compatible and make sure you specify it's path on install

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well.
Try uninstalling strongloop like so: `npm remove strongloop`
Then install it again with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
Make sure it's installed, and run the npm command like so:
`npm install -g strongloop --msvs_version=2012`

Even if you see errors and warnings, ignore them and let it run until it's done.

If you still have errors you can check them in `builderror.log` that should be in:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\ws`